# How can I say "to turn on/off"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

How can I say "to turn on/off" in these contexts:

- I have to turn on my computer first.
- Do you know how to turn off the autocorrect-function?
- Please turn off your phones before entering!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ŝalti kaj malŝalti estas la vortoj, kiujn mi uzas por tio.

*Ŝalti* and *malŝalti* are the words which I use for that.

Answer (score 7):

Use one of these two pairs:

- ŝalti/malŝalti
- enŝalti/elŝalti

They're all fairly common words.